# Visualforce - inline edit support not working in mobile devices

Tags: visualforce, mobile

My Page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Expense__c" extensions="ExpenseController"  sidebar="false" showHeader="true" showChat="false" recordSetVar="exp" >
<script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<apex:form >

<apex:inlineEditSupport />

<apex:pageBlock title="List of Expenses">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!exp}" var="item" >
<apex:column value="{!item.Date__c}"/>

<apex:column value="{!item.Type__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!item.Amount__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!item.Comments__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton1" onclick="alert('Saving the changes...')"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Total" id="theButton2" onclick="alert('Deleting the expense...')"/>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This page's inline edit support is working fine in desktop but when the same page is accessed via tablets or mobile phones the inline editing is not working.

Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: You are accessing through which browser ?

Comment: I tried in Chrome(Samsung Tablet) and Safari(iPhone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because mobile devices can't fire the double click javascript event, instead they would usually interpret this as a double tap and zoom.

There's an idea to allow inline editing from a tap followed by another tap on the pencil icon that appears at :

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gPOmAAM

but there's no comment from product management, which typically means it isn't being actively worked on.